# How to CC current shared mailbox of multiple shared mailboxes?

Tags: vba, outlook

I work in multiple mailboxes.

I was able to make a macro to CC my personal box.

How could I alter this code to CC the shared mailbox I am currently working in as well?

```vb
Public Sub SendAll()
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Set mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
mail.CC = mail.CC & "*Personal E-mail here*"
mail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: Exchange account?

Answer (score 1):

*Try this*

***Exchange account***

```
Mail.CC = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Comment: It is an exchange account.   However, when I use the code you provided it CC's my personal mailbox.  That could be because even though the sent field says "shared mailbox" when I mouse over the shared mailbox address, it says "send using *personal account*" so it is likely recognizing that as the primary user.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ";" symbol

Assume your email is : "your@email.com"

So your code after small change will look like this :

```
Public Sub SendAll()
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Set mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
mail.CC = mail.CC & ";your@email.com"
mail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: I ordinarily do have a semicolon in the code and it cc's my personal box.  However,  it doesn't cc the shared mailbox as well.  I might not have been specific enough originally, but I'm working in a shared mailbox.  So I'm looking to have it CC "Shared mailbox 1" and "personal mailbox".  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're sending the email with the sender address being the shared mailbox you're working from

```
Public Sub SendAll()
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Set mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
mail.CC = mail.Sender & ";your@email.com"
mail.Send
End Sub
```